# assign role on command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm pretty new to python and discord bots in general. I am trying to make it so when a user runs !addrole (role) they will get that role. I need it to work for multiple users and multiple roles. It would be nice if users could also give other users that role.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import random
import discord
from discord.utils import get


my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') #prefix

  

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("admin") 
async def addrole(ctx, *, rolewanted):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = rolewanted
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)


bot.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you're asking.  What issues are you encountering?   Are there any errors?

Comment: I am getting no errors, it just isn't working. I am trying to code it so that when a user runs the command !addrole (roleid) they get assigned that role. I need this to work with multiple roles at once if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to read the documentation, you're code is pretty outdated. You can type hint `member` and `role` to discord objects and use the [`add_roles`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles) method to do what you need

```py
    @bot.command()
    @commands.has_role('admin')
    async def addrole(ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: I saw that, but I was confused, what would the command be that the user would type to get the role? Would it be !addrole (userid) (roleid)?

Comment: `!addrole @user roleid` or `!addrole userid roleid`

Comment: No problem! be sure to mark this as an answer.